# React native - Playing custom sound through ear speaker

Tags: javascript, react-native, audio

A client of mine has asked me if it's possible to play a sound on an iPhone through the ear speaker. Playback can only happen when the phone is held on the users ear (proximity).

I have tried the well known react-native-incall-manager plugin, but after some experimenting i don't think this will do what i want.

Are there any plugins that can do what i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [react-native-proximity](https://github.com/williambout/react-native-proximity), you will probably also need [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound)

If you are looking to only play the event while in a call, you can track that on iOS using callkit, or maintain your own call state in something like redux. Pseudo code for me would be like

```
if in call and sound hasn't played: 
  proximityListener will call play sound
else 
  do nothing
```

```
proximityListener() {
  //play your sound here
}
componentDidMount(){
 Proximity.addListener(this._proximityListener);
},
```